# How to get cookies from a browser using JavaScript and then use them for authorization?

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, xmlhttprequest

This implementation is used for e2e tests, as a workaround to check if file is downloadable instead of actually downloading it.

Currently I am using the following piece of code to get the headers + the status from the particular HEAD request. The issue here is that it doesn't use the authorization from the previous steps, so obviously I will have to authorize again but this time with cookies.

1) How can I get the cookies (I need only `sessionID` cookie) from the browser, I mean from the active session because as I said, I am already logged in? And also store sessionID for example in globals.

2) And how can I send/ use the cookie (`sessionID`) for authorization, in the code provided below?

- I am using JavaScript/ Node.js

  ```
  getHeader: async function (url) {
      var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      url = "{url}.pdf";
      xhr.open("HEAD", url, true);
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (xhr.readyState == this.DONE) {
              console.log('HEADERS:  ' + xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
              console.log('STATUS: ' + xhr.status)
          }
      };
      xhr.send(null);
  },
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use the cookie-parser module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser):

```
var express = require('express')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

var app = express()
app.use(cookieParser())

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  // Cookies that have not been signed
  console.log('Cookies: ', req.cookies)

  // Cookies that have been signed
  console.log('Signed Cookies: ', req.signedCookies)
})

app.listen(8080)
```

Besides this, you can take a look at the ExpressJS documentation for best practices while using cookies:
https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-security.html#use-cookies-securely